# Python re not matching when there is a dot in the string?

Tags: python, regex

It appears that python regex is not matching when the target string has a dot. Is this a feature? Am I missing something? Thanks!

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('txt').match('txt')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f2c424cd648>
>>> re.compile('txt').match('.txt')
>>>
```

Comment: Try to use your regex pattern in here and see what the dot does: https://regex101.com/

Comment: It's not just the dot! Try this: `re.compile('txt').match('hellotxt')`

Comment: What's your input? The `.` represents every character. If you want specifically to match a dot, you need to "escape", using `\.`

Comment: Try 'search' instead of 'match'

Comment: Your title is contradicting your question. Also, the title is correct: It doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are quite explicit about the difference between `search` and `match`:

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).

You should therefore replace `match` with `search`:

```
In [9]: re.compile('txt').search('.txt')
Out[9]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7f888afc9cc8>
```

I don't know the history behind this quirk (which, let's face it, must trip *a lot* of people up), but I'd be interested to see (in the comments) why `re` offers a specific function for matching at the start of a string.

In general, I'm broadly against anything whose name is broad enough that you have to go to the docs to work out what it does.